# How can you call a function in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am new to discord.py and I am stuck on this error. I am trying to call the command removerole later in the code.

This first part works fine, I can type in discord chat:
*.removerole admin Rythm*
And it works, but I get an error in the second part:
`'str' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.command()
async def removerole(ctx, role: discord.Role, member: discord.Member):
    await member.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f'Successfully removed {role.mention} from {member.mention}')
```

I want to type .removeRythm in chat and the bot would remove the admin role from Rythm.

```
@client.command()
async def removeRythm():
    await removerole(".remove", "admin", "Rythm")
```

Does anybody know how to do this if it even is possible to do?
Thanks MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed like so and it now works

```
@client.command()
async def removeRythm():
    await removerole(ctx, ctx.message.guild.get_role(779716603448787004), ctx.message.guild.get_member(235088799074484224))
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You never defined `ctx`

Answer (score 1):

You are passing into the removerole method 3 strings. `".remove", "admin", "Rythm"`. `"Rythm"` is not a discord object but a String. Annotations in Python have no meaning and the compiler totally ignores them. So highlighting that `member` is of type `discord.Member` does not actaully change anything, but only confuses you.

Instead you should pass in a discord user object into the method.

Comment: This is false. Discord.py uses type hinting as converters, for example tagging someone (<@!xxxxxxxxx>) will cast it to the relevant discord.Member instance, same thing for roles, channels, etc. Take a look at the API docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=converter#discord.ext.commands.Converter